# an expression to use like www.* or things.* in vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net

How can I make my program check if a string starts with something in VB.NET?

For example:

```
dim examplestr as string
examplestr = textbox1.text
if examplestr = ("www." + %something%) then
examplestr = ("http://" + examplestr)
elseif examplestr = ("http://" + %something%) then
else
if examplestr = (%something%) then
examplestr = ("http://www." + examplestr
end if
```

Answer (score 7):

Simple:

```
    Dim examplestr As String = "www.example.com"
    Select Case True
        Case examplestr.StartsWith("http://", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
            ' Do nothing?
        Case examplestr.StartsWith("www.", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
            examplestr = "http://" & examplestr
        Case Else
            ' It should be easy to add your own cases.
    End Select
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [regex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx), to find out if a string starts with something, the pattern is simply what it starts with, preceeded by a ^ symbol, something like this:

```
    Dim regex = New Regex("^www\.")
    Console.WriteLine(regex.IsMatch("www.google.com")) 'True
    Console.WriteLine(regex.IsMatch("wwwgooglecom")) 'False
    Console.WriteLine(regex.IsMatch("not a match")) 'False
    Console.WriteLine(regex.IsMatch("awww")) 'False
    Console.ReadLine()
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Matches `"wwwgooglecom"` and `"awww"`. Your code is essentially `s.Contains("www")` not `s.StartsWith("www.")`. The `.` isn't a literal, it's a wildcard and you forgot to match the string start+end.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why nobody mentioned [Like](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swf8kaxw.aspx) operator in VB.NET. You can write like this:

```
Dim examplestr As String = "www.google.com"
If examplestr Like "www.*" Then
  Debug.WriteLine("Hello")
End If
```

It's more simple to use than [Regex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx) and offers slightly more flexibility than [StartsWith](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.startswith.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can also do:

```
If examplestr.StartsWith("www.") Then
    examplestr = ...
End If
```

etc..

Comment: Slightly misleading. `StartsWith()` has been around since forever.